# [iOS]How to make a "snapshot" of the current view's state

Tags: iphone, view

I need to make a snapshot or a screenshot - call it as you like- of the current view and then display it in the modal view.

Because if I just write this in the ModalView's View controller

```
MyAppViewController *viewController = [[MyAppViewController alloc] init];
self.view = viewController.view;
```

All the methods of the MyAppViewController are called as well, but I don't need it, I just need to "save" everything that was on the screen when the ModalView appeared and show it in the ModalView's view.

How can I do it?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm not sure what this means: "All the methods of the MyAppViewController are called as well". An answer that seems far too obvious to me would be to just create a new class with just the elements you need. Surely I don't understand the problem well enough though.

Comment: My app is a game. And when user taps a specific button a Modal View Controller appears and it needs to display the View of the game in the state which was just before the button was tapped. So monsters that were killed should be dead etc. But If I use the code from the first post, everything looks like the game has just begun

Comment: do you need a flat image screenshot, or are you looking to save the current status of the game.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

I would suggest doing this:

Have a method that creates an image out of the contents of the view.

```
-(UIImage*) makeImage {

UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.bounds.size);

[self.view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];

UIImage *viewImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

return viewImage;
}
```

Create a custom init method for your modal view, and also give your modalView an instance variable that can hold a UIImage something like...

```
- (id)initWithImage:(UIImage *)temp {
   myImage = temp;
}
```

Then in your modalView, perhaps in the viewDidLoad method, create a UIImageView and set the image to `myImage`

Hopefully this achieves what you are trying to do.

Comment: Yes! That's exactly what I've needed! Thank you so much!

Comment: On retina display, using UIGraphicsBeginImageContext creates a context with 1.0 scale factor, which results in low resolution images.
Use UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.view.bounds.size, YES, 0.0) to automatically have the correct scale factor.

Comment: You'll want to add the `QuartzCore` framework in `Build Phases` and `#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>` in the file were you access the view's layer.

Comment: Important, as Imre Kelényi is saying, use UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.view.bounds.size, YES, 0.0) for retina.

Answer (score 12):

In iOS 7, you can use one of the new methods in UIView for creating snapshots, for instance:

```
- (UIView *)snapshotViewAfterScreenUpdates:(BOOL)afterUpdates;
```

which returns a UIView which you can then add as a subview.

Answer (score 0):

```
UIView *viewSnapShop = [self snapshotViewAfterScreenUpdates:NO];
```