# Instantiate View behind current ViewController

Tags: iphone, uiview, uiviewcontroller, subview

I want to instantiate a viewController and place it behind the currently shown view. Then move  the original view's fram to reveal the view behind it.

I CANNOT create the bottom view first and add the top view on top. I will be creating multiple bottom views and memory can't handle the whole stack at once.

Problems I've already encountered.

- Adding a subView and sending it to the back means moving the original view's frame move's the entire view, not revealing the new one.
- Instantiating the new view and calling `presentViewController` deallocs the original view (if I add it modally)

Can anyone help? Or lead me in a direction?

Comment: Presenting a second view controller modally will NOT dealloc the view controller that did the presenting. Using presentingViewController will give you a pointer back to that VC

Answer (score 1):

Is it fair to say you're going for a transition from vc1 to vc2 where what you want is *the appearance* that vc2 was underneath vc1 and vc1 slid out of the way to reveal it?

If so, then that's doable without doing anything unusual or dangerous from the sdk perspective.  The trick is to do the normal instantiate and present steps, but in vc1, before presenting vc2, hand it a UIImage that looks like vc1.  Vc2 covers itself with that image before it appears, then slides the image out of the way to reveal itself.

Here are the steps:

1) On vc1, implement the method [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3710127/ioshow-to-make-a-snapshot-of-the-current-views-state).  It captures an image of the view.

2) There's some action that makes you want to present vc2, do it like this...

```
- (void)presentVc2:(id)sender {
    UIImage *image = [self makeImage];  // it was called makeImage in the other post, consider a better name
    MyViewController2 *vc2 = [[MyViewController2 alloc] initWithNibName:@"MyViewController2" bundle:nil];
    vc2.presentationImage = image;  // more on this later

    // this line will vary depending on if you're using a container vc, but the key is
    // to present vc2 with NO animation
    [self presentViewController:vc2 animated:NO completion:^{}];
}
```

3) Create a UIImage property on MyViewController2 called presentationImage and make it's setter public.  Then in MyViewController2 ...

```
// before we appear, cover with the last vc's image
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:self.presentationImage];
    imageView.frame = self.view.bounds;
    imageView.tag = 128;
    [self.view addSubview:imageView];
}

// after we appear, animate the removal of that image
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    UIImageView *imageView = (UIImageView *)[self.view viewWithTag:128];
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{
        imageView.frame = CGRectOffset(imageView.frame, -self.frame.size.width, 0); 
    }];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could simply put the top view's contents into a new UIView whose frame is equal to your view controller's view's frame. Then stick your bottom views below the container view. Moving the container view, then, will move all of its contents but leave the bottom views in tact.