# How To Share On Facebook And Twitter (Social Framework) by taking screenshot from another ViewController?

Tags: ios, facebook, swift, swift2

In my app, when the user clicks shareToFacebook button, I need my app to take a screenshot from another ViewController which just has got the score, and share it to Facebook. So I wrote the code like this: (It works pretty well), :

Now, my doubt is: in order to take that screenshot from another ViewController which has got the score, what code should I put into this :

```
@IBAction func sharetoFacebook() {
var sharetoFacebook : SLComposeViewController = 
SLComposeViewController(forServiceType:
SLServiceTypeFacebook)
sharetoFacebook.setInitialText("WOW! I scored \(rightCounter) right..! Wanna challenge me?")
shareToFacebook.addImage(UIImage(named: "//What should I put here ?"))
self.presentViewController(sharetoFacebook, animated:
    true, completion: nil)  }

shareToFacebook.addImage(UIImage(named: "//What should I put here ?"))
```

After searching, I found solution like : `//I put this code inside the ViewController that I want to take screenshot`

```
func snapshot() -> UIImage {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.view.bounds.size, false, UIScreen.mainScreen().scale)

        self.view.drawViewHierarchyInRect(self.view.bounds, afterScreenUpdates: true)

    let sreenshotImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    return screenshotImage // Im getting error over here: saying: UIImageview not convertible to UIImage
}
```

But then I got some errors like :

When I put : `shareToFacebook.addImage(scoreVC.snapshot()) //Not in the ViewController I want to take screenshot`

I got error as : `Im getting missing argument for parameter #1`

And for the above code, `func snapshot() -> UIImageView {`

I get the error saying `UIImageView not convertible to UIImage`

Please help me out..! Thanks in advance..!  It would be a great help!

Here's the current error :
[image]

Answer (score 0):

you need to declare the `snapshot` method into the score viewcontroller, or if you prefer you can use a category on `UIViewController`.

Now when you want to share the image you just need:

```
shareToFacebook.addImage(scoreVC.snapshot())
```

Comment: I declared the snapshot method onto the scoreViewController. Note that: Im using this `shareToFacebook.addImage(scoreVC.snapshot())` inside the ViewController where the screenshot is not there. Im calling it..I think it works fine..but I get the error as `missing argument for parameter #1` How to solve that ? Please help!

Comment: @rmaddy Please help me..!

Comment: The `addImage` method requires just an instance of `UIImage` as you case see from the definition `func addImage(image: UIImage!) -> Bool` so passing the snapshot as a parameter should be enough.

Comment: But IM getting the error `UIImageView not convertible to UIImage` and ` missing argument for parameter #1`

Comment: your implementation of the `snapshot` method returns an `UIImage` and  the `addImage` requires an `UIImage` so everything should be fine and I cannot see where you pass the `UIImageView` I will suggest you to review the source code and update your original question with the right code.

Comment: I got a UIImageView in the Score ViewController ! Note that: IM typing this code in : `shareToFacebook.addImage(scoreVC.snapshot())` another viewcontroller // The ViewController which does not have the score.

Comment: If you implemented the snapshot method in the right way, as you posted here there is no way to receive an `UIImageView`  check also this implementation of the snapshot method http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3710127/ioshow-to-make-a-snapshot-of-the-current-views-state

Comment: So, you are saying that the above code is totally correct and it works..? So, why might be I getting those errors then ? :(

Comment: When I type exactly as above and when i type this command : ` return screenshotImage // Im getting error over here: saying: UIImageview not convertible to UIImage` I get this error...please help me fix..! :) Thanks..!

Comment: But when I put func snapshot() -> UIImageView { : // It works perfectly..! No errors..

Comment: Please don't leave me alone like this ! :(

Comment: Ples update your question using the final version of the code you arte using.

Comment: Updated ! Check out this portion : `func snapshot() -> UIImageView { :` Note that if I put the code like `func snapshot() -> UIImage { :` I get the error as `UIImageView not convertible to UIImage` near `return screenshotImage`

Comment: the `addImage` require an `UIImage` as parameter so you cannot use your implementation of the `snapshot` because you are returning an `UIImageView`.  Replacing your method with this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3710127/ioshow-to-make-a-snapshot-of-the-current-views-state

Comment: I got that part right..! Phew..! Now Im having error only here : `shareToFacebook.addImage(scoreVC.snapshot())` as `missing argument for parameter #1`

Comment: Yeah Now Im getting the error `() not convertible to UIImage` when I type `sharetoFacebook.addImage(ShareSuccess.snapshot())`

Comment: I have updated the Question Details...uploaded the picture of error.

Comment: Snapshot is an instance method, not a class method.

Comment: So, how will I fix it ?

Comment: You need to have access to the right instance of the `ShareSuccess`, only if you have access to this instance you can call the instance method in the right way. Somewhere you have your `var shareVC :ShareSuccess = .....` and then you can call `shareToFacebook.addImage(shareVC.snapshot())` And btw, SO is not a discussion board.